# How can I get a timezone set automatically according to location service?

Tags: macos, timezone

My environment is 10.13.4 (High Sierra).

I turn on `Set date and time automatically` and  want to acquire the timezone.

I am aware of `systemsetup -gettimezone` which only can run with `sudo`, however, it returns the timezone set by `TZ=foo/hoge` in my rcscript.

I want to acquire the computer's current, automatically-set time zone via the command line.

Comment: So you're trying to acquire the computer's current, automatically-set time zone via the command line? The question is worded a little odd.

Answer (score 1):

Launch System Preferences. Select "Date & Time", then open the "Time Zone" panel. (If necessary, authenticate as Administrator to unlock.) Click in the checkbox to turn on "Set time zone automatically using current location"

Comment: Thanks, I rephrase my question. How can I get an automatically set location via terminal??